configStore is not defined at setup
Upon trying to run my Vue/Nuxt application I am greeted by a 500 error code and an error message:

configStore is not defined at setup


provide the code of the usage of your pinia store.

In my case this error popped up when I was trying to use a Pinia store in another store's action.
Moving the line const overviewStore = useOverviewStore() into a component instead solved the issue
